# How to setup DNS records for 1 domain to use 2 servers?

Tags: dns

I have an app for example: `app.com`

And I would like to have some subdomains for it:

- `blog.app.com`
- `forum.app.com`
- `etc.app.com`

I have two servers with the IP's:

- **Server A**: `127.0.0.0`
- **Server B**: `127.0.0.1`

I would like to host the `app.com` on **`Server A`**. And all the subdomains on **`Server B`**.

How should I set up the DNS records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you should be able to this:

```
app.com. IN A 127.0.0.0
sub.app.com. IN A 127.0.0.1
...
```

Pointing the root of the domain to server A, and then each subdomain can have a pointer to the other domain.

Comment: Rhis is something like what I though myself too, but it's a bit confusing, so should I point all the subdomains to the `sub.app.com`?

Comment: Sure you could do that. You can make an `A` record called `server-b.app.com` and then use a `CNAME` to alias all the subdomains to that